# Why is my stored procedure not visible to ASP.NET?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Ok, so the stored procedure does actually exist (I can see it in SQL Manager) and the database user that I'm connecting with has access to it (it is the db_owner) but I'm getting an error message stating that `The stored procedure 'proc_Name' doesn't exist.` Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the connection string in right way or the name of the stored procedure?

Comment: Are you using the correct database?

Comment: The connection string is in the web.config. It definitely connects to the database.

Comment: Yes I'm using the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

It was an orphaned user in the end.